# Bugsnag: No API key configured, couldn't notify when deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, bugsnag

I have a standard rails 4 app deployed on heroku.

I'm trying to add bugsnag to it.

First:

- I create a new project in the Bugsnag UI (https://bugsnag.com/accounts/jobteaser/projects/new),
- Select rails,
- `rails generate bugsnag <API_KEY_FROM_BUGSNAG_UI>`

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bugsnag'
```

**config/initializers/bugsnag.rb**

```
Bugsnag.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = '<API_KEY_FROM_BUGSNAG_UI>'
end
```

**lib/tasks/test_exception.rake**

```
namespace :myapp do

  desc 'Test task that raises an exception'
  task :test_exception do
    raise 'This is a sample exception'
  end

end
```

- Then I commit, push and deploy with `git push heroku master`
- make sure heroku is up-to-date `heroku restart`

Then `heroku run rake myapp:test_exception`

=>

```
Running rake myapp:test_exception on ⬢ myapp... up, run.2877 
W, [2016-06-27T12:23:56.017117 #3]  
WARN -- : ** [Bugsnag] No API key configured, couldn't notify rake aborted! 
This is a sample exception 
/app/lib/tasks/test_exception.rake:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bugsnag-4.2.1/lib/bugsnag/rake.rb:12:in `execute_with_bugsnag' 
Tasks: TOP => jd:sample_exception 
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I want heroku to send exception to bugsnag. What did I miss?

**Note:** The bugsnag integration works fine (I see the exception in the bugsnag UI) if I run the command locally, eg: `rake myapp:test_exception`

Answer (score 0):

My task was missing `:environment`, causing heroku to **not** load the initializers before executing the task.

If I rewrite the task like this, bugsnag receives the exception:

```
namespace :myapp do

  desc 'Test task that raises an exception'
  task test_exception: :environment do # <- added :environment here
    raise 'This is a sample exception'
  end

end
```

---

Another reason your errors are not received by bugsnag is if you are running in another context or dyno.

For example, inside a sidekiq job, you need to use a specific gem (see [Handle exception in Sidekiq 3 jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269388)).

In my case, I am running background jobs with [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork). In order to instrument them, I had to do the following (this is specific to clockwork):

```
# File config/clock.rb

require 'clockwork'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork

  error_handler do |error|
    Bugsnag.auto_notify(error)
  end

  # Check bugsnag is not dead
  every(1.day, 'ping_bugsnag', at: '09:00') do
    raise 'ping bugsnag'
  end

  # ... Other jobs here

end
```

For more custom bugsnag instrumentation, see https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-ruby/blob/master/lib/bugsnag/sidekiq.rb